# Book about a good dark lord, think "not Sauron"

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I started reading this book earlier this year at my library and haven’t been able to find it again.

It is about a “dark” lord who was once part of a group of gods? Godlike beings? I think there were seven (maybe more, maybe less). They had some disagreement about how life should work (free will related? the “dark” lord felt kind of promethean) had a war between him and the others, one of the others was noted as being the strongest. The war was a draw.

There was a cataclysm (I remember he had dragons on his side). He stole a McGuffin that belonged to the eldest (strongest?) of the others. The McGuffin was some kind of weapon/repository of power that the other gods wanted to use to start over (something like that).

He ended up on a separate continent from them, across a vast ocean (formed from their war I think). He built some kind of fortress (think Mordor) with “orcs” (*not orcs* called something else, but, they are orcs/trollocs/generic fantasy bad) he had 9(±) special generals/followers/*not ringwraiths* who he made “immortal” (I think they can be killed, but won't die of natural causes).

I think the book had elves.

It had a very "this is lord of the rings told from the view of Sauron" feel to it. The story, at least as much of it that I read, was mostly being told from the viewpoint of one of his human generals (they might all have been human).

The plot points I gave were mostly the prologue to the main plot of the book.
I didn’t get far into the book, so I don’t know much more than that. I don't know if it's enough to go on.

It is not [*"The Last Ringbearer"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Ringbearer).

Comment: So, he actually was a benevolent overlord?

Comment: Some of the points raised sound like Torak from the Belgariad and Malloreon...  7 gods, Orb of Aldur, Cataclysm creating the Sea of the East...  Torak was not "good" though and no "Elves" nor 9 followers..  Torak's host were human instead of Orcs (although Murgos had scarred faces.  That story is mostly in Belgarath the Sorcerer iirc

Comment: Does he have a group of followers that are his because he pays them lots of money? Very mercenary...

Are the troll-like creatures created by the goddess of life, come from high/cold mountains, and his because he promised to help them?

Does he kidnap an elvish princess starting a war between the followers of dark and the light gods?

Comment: Did you ask the librarian?

Comment: You said, "good," but I wonder if maybe you meant "protagonist" instead. Tales in which the protagonist is not a "good" person are less common than the other kind, but I think they've probably been around for almost as long as literature itself.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, I meant good. It is Banewreaker I haven't read more of the book yet so I don't know how morally grey Sartoris is. What I do remember is he came across a Prometheus stand in. Which is something I would consider to be good. There might be darker sides to him in the story as the plot moves on, however, at least the beginning of the book paints him as a being who has been on the wrong end of a successful propaganda campaign

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Is it [Banewreaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banewreaker) by Jacqueline Carey?

What matches. There is Sartoris (Morgoth, but good). He fights the God of light, Haomane who is the eldest/strongest. They break a mystic jewel which shatters into 2 pieces. The largest piece is a sword called God-Slayer, Sartoris is stabbed by it, doesn't die, but is crippled, he gets the sword and hides in a fortress he creates called Darkhaven (Think Mordor). The other Gods are convinced by Haomane to flee the world (Haomane flees because he fears that Sartoris will kill him, the others because they believe Haomane's lies).

There are no orcs, only Trolls, Weres, and Staccians (Human mercenaries).

There are Ellylon. Which are elves by a different name.

There is a prophecy that foretells Sartoris death.

There are only 3 Immortals, not 9.

The viewpoint character is Tanaros Blacksword, his Lord General, the kingslayer (killed his wife and king who were having an affair, and had a child). Who is a human.

The other 2 are:

Ushashin Dreamspinner, half human half Ellyon. Leader of the insane and unwanted.

Lord Vorax a Staccian (humans that follow Darkhaven, in exchange for money/food... Its a very tit/tat relationship).

Comment: this is it! I probably got the 9 from mentally just equating them with nazgul, but this is absolutely the story

Comment: @TorstenGang Acknowledged by the author to be based on *Lord of the Rings*, telling the other side of the story.

Comment: "hides in a fortress he creates called Darkhaven (Think Mordor)" - Sounds more like Utumno (since this is Morgoth we're talking about).

Comment: @void_ptr... I am not to familiar with the Similarion.. But Darkhaven definitely gave me Mordor vibes.